# ItemUpdated Event, After or Before Property Title name is null

Tags: 2010, development, itemupdated

No matter what I do, before and after for title are always null. 
This is an item updated receiver in the meetings or event list

```
![public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "BEGIN");
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            try
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                SPSite site = properties.Web.Site;
                string sitename= properties.BeforeProperties\["Title"\].ToString();
                SPWeb web = site.RootWeb.Webs\[sitename\];
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                string prefix = properties.BeforeProperties\["Title"\].ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                web.Title = properties.AfterProperties\["Title"\].ToString();
                DateTime eventDate = properties.AfterProperties.GetValueAsDateTime(MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_EVENTDATE_NAME);
                if (eventDate != DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    string titleMeetingCalendarItem = eventDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    titleMeetingCalendarItem = string.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, titleMeetingCalendarItem);
                    properties.AfterProperties.SetAfterPropertyValue("Title", titleMeetingCalendarItem);
                    web.ServerRelativeUrl = "/" + titleMeetingCalendarItem;               
                }
                web.Update();

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", ex);
                properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                properties.Cancel = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
            Logger.LogDebug("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "END");
        }][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the ItemUpdating instead of the itemupdated event. In the itemupdated event, there aren't any before and after properties! Only while updatING...

Comment: I dont think thats correct. http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: but yes, I suppose I can use the item updating event.

Comment: the code doesnt work either on item updating event., beforeproperties["Title"] is always null

Comment: If you look at the blog post you linked to, it says that beforeproperties is always NULL in a list, use properties.ListItem instead.